# Cannot Get Typeahead.js Working with MVC 5 Over Remote

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but I cannot get typeahead working in my MVC 5 application.  I installed everything via NuGet and my view includes `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/typeahead")`, which is rendering properly when viewing the source of the view.  So the issue isn't that the dependencies are missing.

I am not seeing any drop down appear when I start typing, and using Fiddler I do not see any calls being made out to the remote that I setup that pulls the data.

Here's the line in my view that typeahead is being attached:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MainInfo.CompanyName, 
         new { @class = "form-control typeahead", id = "comp-name", autocomplete="off" })
```

Here's the portion of my script that configures typeahead and bloodhound:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var clients = new Bloodhound({
         datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
             return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
         },
         queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
         remote: {
             url: "/info/client?like=%QUERY",
             wildcard: '%QUERY',
             filter: function (clients) {
                 return $.map(clients, function (client) {
                     return {
                         value: client.Name,
                         clientId: client.Identifier
                     };
                 });
             }
         }
    });

    clients.initialize();

    $('#comp-name').typeahead(null,
    {
        display: 'value',
        minLength: 1,
        source: clients.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: "Looks like a new client...",
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<p><b>{{value}}</b> - {{clientId}}</p>")
        }
    });
});
```

Is there something that I've configured wrong in my javascript?  I've used a few tutorials as well as their own documentation, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here.  It almost feels like it's not properly initialized, but there are no errors being thrown.

*NOTE:*  Just as an FYI I'm using Bootstrap 3 as well in case that changes anything.

**EDIT:** Here's my `@section Scripts`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/typeahead")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/handlebars.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ProjectSetupFormScripts.js")"></script> <-- this is where typeahead is set up
```

Comment: What version of Typeahead are you using?

Comment: @BenSmith I believe it was version 0.11.1, but I was never able to get it to work properly.  I switched to [selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) instead, which has been working flawlessly and I found far easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

**JS**

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        SetupTipeahead();
    });
    function SetupTipeahead() {
        var engine = new Bloodhound({
            remote: {
                url: '/Employees/AllEmployees',
                ajax: {
                    type: 'GET'
                }
            },
            datumTokenizer: function (d) {
                return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.FullName);
            },
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
        });

        engine.initialize();

        $('#FullName').typeahead(null, {
            displayKey: 'FullName',
            source: engine.ttAdapter(),
            templates: {
                empty: [
                                    '<div class="empty-message">',
                                    'No match',
                                    '</div>'
                ].join('\n'),
                suggestion: function (data) {
                    return '<p class="">' + data.FullName + '</p><p class="">' + data.ManNumber + '</p>';
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**EmployeesController** has the following `JsonResult`

```
        public JsonResult AllEmployees()
    {
        return Json(db.Employees.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to wrap your script in `@section scripts {}` this will place the script at the bottom just before the `</body>` tag and make sure you are not calling the function before your bundles load.

```
@section scripts {
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

     var clients = new Bloodhound({
         datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
             return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
         },
         queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
         remote: {
             url: "/info/client?like=%QUERY",
             wildcard: '%QUERY',
             filter: function (clients) {
                 return $.map(clients, function (client) {
                     return {
                         value: client.Name,
                         clientId: client.Identifier
                     };
                 });
             }
         }
    });

    clients.initialize();

    $('#comp-name').typeahead(null,
    {
        display: 'value',
        minLength: 1,
        source: clients.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: "Looks like a new client...",
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile("<p><b>{{value}}</b> - {{clientId}}</p>")
        }
    });
});
</script>
}
```

Comment: The script is external, but it's already linked within the scripts section.